# Where can I find a list of unlock conditions for ingredients?

Tags: the-sushi-spinnery

I'm stuck at a point in my game where my ingredients don't seem to be good enough to win any contests (namely, the first maki challenge, and the 4 star contests).  My sushi-chefs are mostly level 8-9 and I don't have anything else to research.  I have all the ingredients/PR, etc that I can currently get.  No matter what I try, I can't win first place in the contests without better ingredients.  Where can I find the conditions required to unlock them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a list [here](http://adeptgamer.com/forum/pages/the-sushi-spinnery-guide/) (under the "food" tab):

[image: Not a wall of text with bad spacing]